# C# Mock Delegate throw exception of type Conversion

Tags: c#, delegates, nunit, .net-core-3.1

I have delegate which pointing to method with no parameter and it return list of object data List.
I am using nUnit, fixture and mock for the testing. I have created list of records that I like my static method to mock with via delegate but I am getting error

```
 appTenantListHandlerMoq.Setup(_ => _).Returns(tenantsMoq);
```

[image: enter code here]

`MyClass`

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public delegate Task<IEnumerable<AppTenant>> AppTenantListHandler();
    
    AppTenantListHandler appTenantListHandler;


    public MyClass ()
    {
        appTenantListHandler = new AppTenantListHandler(GetTenant);
    }

    public async Task Run(){
        var tenantList = await appTenantListHandler();
    }

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<AppTenant>> GetTenant()
    {
       List<AppTenant> dataList = new List<AppTenant>();
       
       return dataList;
        
    }
}
```

`Test Class`

```
 [TestFixture]
public class MyClassTests
{
    private readonly MyClass sut;
    private Mock<MyClass> MyClassMoq;

    private readonly Mock<ILogger> loggerMoq;
    private readonly Mock<ITelemetryInitializer> telemetryInitializerMoq;
    
    


    public MyClassTests()
    {
        this.loggerMoq = new Mock<ILogger>();
        this.telemetryInitializerMoq = new Mock<ITelemetryInitializer>();
        this.MyClassMoq = new Mock<MyClass>();

        this.sut = new MyClass(loggerMoq.Object);
    }
    
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
       
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //Arrange
        var fixture  = new Fixture();

        var tenantsMoq = fixture.CreateMany<AppTenant>(5);

        var appTenantListHandlerMoq = new Mock<MyClass.AppTenantListHandler>();

        appTenantListHandlerMoq.Setup(_ => _).Returns(tenantsMoq);


        //Act
        var actualResult = sut.RunAsync(this.telemetryInitializerMoq.Object);

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(actualResult);
    }
}
```

`Error2`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock a delegate, the syntax is :

```cs
appTenantListHandlerMoq.Setup(_ => _()).Returns(Task.FromResult(tenantsMoq));
```

But in your case, this will do noting, but the instance `sut` don't call the mocked delegate. You need to modify `MyClass`  to inject the mocked delegate like :

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
    public delegate Task<IEnumerable<AppTenant>> AppTenantListHandler();
    
    AppTenantListHandler appTenantListHandler;


    public MyClass ()
        : this(new AppTenantListHandler(GetTenant))
    { }

    public MyClass (AppTenantListHandler appTenantListHandler )
    {
        this.appTenantListHandler = appTenantListHandler ;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in the test :

```cs
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    //Arrange
    var fixture  = new Fixture();
    var tenantsMoq = fixture.CreateMany<AppTenant>(5);
    var appTenantListHandlerMoq = new Mock<MyClass.AppTenantListHandler>();
    appTenantListHandlerMoq.Setup(_ => _()).Returns(Task.FromResult(tenantsMoq));
    MyClass sut = new MyClass(appTenantListHandlerMoq);

    //Act
    var actualResult = sut.RunAsync(this.telemetryInitializerMoq.Object);

    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(actualResult);
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks vernou, I am getting new error, I have pasted at the end of my question also what If I have multiple delegates ?

Comment: My answer don't have `ReturnAysnc`. But I miss that the delegate return a task. I updated my answer.

Comment: But I am still getting error

Comment: With multiple delegate, you need to inject all mocked delegate. But maybe a interface will be a better fit. To more information, you can search about "dependency injection" or "expected dependency" on the web.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I pasted at the end of my question under `error2`

Comment: Where does `ReturnAsync` come from? Can you just use `Return`?

Comment: Maybe you have pasted my example before I fix it... my bad. Can you replace `ReturnAsync` by `Return`?

Comment: I have tried with RuturnAsync ... still same issue

Comment: Shame on me... I haven't saved the fix in my answer.

Comment: Can you try this `appTenantListHandlerMoq.Setup(_ => _()).Returns(Task.FromResult(tenantsMoq));`?